# double coset, stabilizer and orbits

Tags: group-theory

> $G$ is a finite group. $H\le G$, $D$ is a set. $x \in D$. $G$ acts transitively on $D$. Show that the mapping $HgG_x \mapsto Hgx$ is a well-defined bijection from the set of double cosets $\{HgG_x: g \in G\}$ to the set of orbits $\{Hy: y \in D\}$.

Comment: You will need $G$ to act transitively on $D$ for this to work. Unless you mean the set of $H$-orbits residing within the $G$-orbit of $x$ specifically.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For $h \in H$, $g \in G$, and $g' \in G_x$ we have $Hhgg'x=Hgx$ since $Hh=H$ and $g'x=x$. So the map is well-defined. It is surjective since the $G$-action is transitive. Suppose now that two double cosets, rep'd by $g_1$ and $g_2$ go to the same $H$-orbit in $D$. Then $g_1 x$ and $g_2 x$ are in the same $H$-orbit, so $g_2 x=h g_1 x$ for some $h \in H$, implying that $g_1^{-1} h^{-1} g_2 \in G_x$ and hence $$g_2=h g_1 (g_1^{-1} h^{-1} g_2) \in H g_1 G_x.$$